# ¿Cómo agregar un title (metadata) a una page en Next.js 13 si la page es 'use client'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs

eh encontrado varias respuesta aquí y allá, que van desde usar un useEffect hasta crear un layout.jsx solo para poder agregar el title, y si bien estas y otras aproximaciones más funcionan, no pude encontrar en la documentación oficial una solución que no sea al *tun tun*. ¿Alguien estaría sabiendo cuál es la mejor manera de encarar esta problemática?

Aclaración: me refiero a las versiones de nextJS que hacen uso del **app router** (^13) en las que la manera de aplicar el title, siguiendo la documentación oficial, es la de exportar una objeto "metadata"

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'example',
}
```

Lo cual no es posible si dicha page no se renderiza en el servidor (es decir, cuando añadimos el *'use client';* en la primera línea.

Comment: ya sabes la respuesta, no trates de encontrar algo que no existe. crea un `layout.ts` (para eso son) o mueve la lógica del cliente a componentes fuera del `page.ts` y deja que el page sea un `server` component y sus hijos `client` components. esa es la manera en la que se hace en Next 13.

Answer (score 0):

**Hola @Sancaf**
La única forma es que lo manejes en un hook useEffect desde document y valides si existe o no, y ahi coloques el título que necesites.

```
document.head.title ?   
document.querySelector("title") = "my-title":
document.head.innerHTML = <title>{my-title}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
```

Después:

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata | null> {
   const title = `Titulo aquí`;

   return {
      title
   }
}
```

Comment: Error => You are attempting to export "generateMetadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed.

Comment: Que hace este código? Las respuestas con unicamente código no suelen ser bien recibidas.